# Handle state variable initialization

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, mern

I'm trying to fill form data using state variable. Data of state variable is getting from redux store as shown below :

```
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(post && post.location);
  const [hastage, setHastage] = useState(post && post.hastage);
  const [caption, setCaption] = useState(post && post.caption);
  const [postImg, setPostImg] = useState(post && post.postImg);
```

In above code 'post' is redux store instance.

Every thing is working Fine. However, **Problem** is that :

When I refresh page 'post' data is async call therefore before getting post data all variable is initialized with " "(Blank). and form is getting empty.

Hoe to initialize all state variable after 'post' data is ready ?

Comment: why do you declare new states and fill them by redux states? why you don't use redux states instead of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize all state value inside of a `useEffect` hook, which can allow you to perform some execution after after the DOM have been rendered.

Firstly you 'll initialize all state to an empty string like this

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
const [hastage, setHastage] = useState('');
const [caption, setCaption] = useState('');
const [postImg, setPostImg] = useState('');
```

And in the second place you will add `useEffect` which will allow you to perform side effect

```
useEffect(() => {
    // here you can check for existence of any attribute on the `post` object
    if(post && post.location) {
        setLocation(post.location);
    }
    // etc.
}, [post]);
```

You can also pass the `post` object to the second argument of the `useEffect` hook, this will trigger the rerender of the component each time the value of `post` change.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a conditional expression which only returns the form if the data has some value in it and when its fetching some value you could do something like a loading screen or a spinner hiding the form,etc. You could technically add an extra value in redux just for tracking this and when that value changes you display the form. Also you could try to disable the form fields just as a extra suggestion.

```
return (<div>{post.hasLoaded ? <MyForm /> : 'Loading...'}</div>);
```

or

```
return (<div>{post && post.location ? <MyForm />:'Loading..'}</div>);
```

Comment: Thanks. but, still variables get initialized before it. using this Technik can stop rending of form, when form would be render with empty variables.

Comment: @DhruvalBhuva you can use this technique inside the form elements and make them disabled like  <input type="text" disabled="true"/> and in place of true just use the expression. Otherwise, You can fade out the form and load the spinner on top of it while this is happening. I believe that you want the user not to input any value when the initial request is happening

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `useEffect` with `post` as a dependency, where it updates all states values if `post` exists.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (post) {
    setLocation(post.location)
    setHastage(post.hastage)
    setCaption(post.caption)
    setPostImg(post.postImg)
  }
}, [post])
```